# Add Thumbnail to a jssor video-gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jssor

Hi anyone can help me add an image thumbnail in a video gallery? Here is my site: [skinwhitening101.weebly.com][1]

[1]: http://skinwhitening101.weebly.com , As you can see in my home page I use Jssor slider and my video gallery has only number thumbnail. I tried to copy and paste some codes from other slide with an image thumbnail but doesn't seem to work. I modify some codes and put an image on the thumbnail but still not working. Pleaase Help!

Answer (score 0):

Please go through 3 steps to enable thumbnail navigator.

1. Add $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions to initialize jssor slider.

   ```
   var options = {
       ...
       $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {                       //[Optional] Options to specify and enable thumbnail navigator or not
           $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,              //[Required] Class to create thumbnail navigator instance
           $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always

           $ActionMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None, 1 act by click, 2 act by mouse hover, 3 both, default value is 1
           $SpacingX: 8,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
           $Cols: 10,                             //[Optional] Number of pieces to display, default value is 1
           $Align: 360                           //[Optional] The offset position to park thumbnail
       },
       ...
   };
   ```
2. Add thumbnail navigator skin in your slider container,

   ```
   <div id="slider1_container" ...>
       ...
       <!-- Thumbnail Navigator Skin Begin -->
       <!-- open skin\thumbnail-xx.source.html, copy/paste thumbnail navigator skin herer -->
       <!-- Thumbnail Navigator Skin End -->
       ...
   </div>
   ```
3. Add thumbnail element in every slide (<img u="thumb" src="url" />),

   ```
   <div u="slides" ...>
       <div>
           <img u="image" src="../img/alila/01.jpg" />
           <img u="thumb" src="../img/alila/thumb-01.jpg" />
       </div>
       <div>
           <img u="image" src="../img/alila/02.jpg" />
           <img u="thumb" src="../img/alila/thumb-02.jpg" />
       </div>
       ...
   </div>
   ```